# android displaying image after capture

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

I have requirement like I have a custom Horizontal ScrollView with text and image(image which is invisible) and button to start camera intent.

When I select any item I am getting Id of that scroll item. When I click on button to capture photo my code is taking photo and getting the path from sdcard.but image view is not getting visibility even when I use imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); this line code.

ImageView I declared globally in main class.

Please give me an idea in this issue.

=============================================================================

This is the code I done after capturing photo inside on

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inSampleSize = 5;
                bb = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile.getAbsolutePath(),
                        options);
                MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),
                        bb, null, null);

                System.out.println("Bitmap is : " + bb);
                System.out.println("Tab Id to keep photo is : " + tabId);

                imageView.setImageBitmap(bb);
                imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                filePath = imageFile.getAbsolutePath();
```

Thanks,
UdaySekhar

Comment: you should use `imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` to show the view instead of `imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)`

Comment: Hi nikis I used the same what u mentioned. I confused and added it.